# decrease Wildfly connection timeouts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, connection, wildfly

I have a problem with resource starvation on my java application running in wildfly.
It is making a lot of API calls to other REST resources, and if one of these API:s is slowed down, our system goes down as well.

It has happened that the backend systems are not responding within 14 seconds. So I would like my application to break the connection after maybe 4 seconds.
The "problem" is that we are using `Client` and `ClientBuilder` from `javax.ws.rs.client` and we are using wildfly as an implementation.

So I have no idea how to set this timeout parameter. It doesn't appear to be possible from code, and I'm quite lost as to which wildfly subsystem is affected and what properties to set.

Has anyone done this before and know how to set the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CONNECT_TIMEOUT Jersey client property as show those posts:

- http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/implementing_connect_and_read_timeouts
- http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/setting_timeout_for_the_jax
- http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/setting_timeout_for_jax_rs

Comment: I had no idea that this was standardized in java ee 8... since we are currently on 7 and not using any of the vendors you linked, I should probably look into upgrading our environment to java EE 8

Comment: I think the migration is not mandatory to use this feature, this [post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/setting_timeout_for_the_jax) was published in 2014 so it is able in Jersey from a time ago. You can try first with the version you already have to check if a migration is really needed.

Comment: And, don't forget to mark the answer if you this helped you to solve your doubt :)

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to try it out before I approved it. In our specific case though, we are not using jersey as an implementation, which makes it particularly difficult to test this out

Answer (score 0):

So since wildfly comes bundled with resteasy you have to implement a timeout for that specific implementation. That or force wildfly to use something else. Since forceing jersey upon wildfly didn't seem like the best of ideas(or the easiest) I went with configuring it.

http://blog.eisele.net/2014/12/setting-timeout-for-jax-rs-20-resteasy-client.html

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;

 Client client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                .establishConnectionTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .socketTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
```

and I've added the following in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that both **establishConnectionTimeout** and **socketTimeout** are deprecated.

With this explanation on jboss v7.3 by [redhat website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html-single/developing_web_services_applications/index) :

> The following ClientBuilder specification-compliant methods replace certain deprecated RESTEasy methods:
>
> - The **connectTimeout** method replaces the **establishConnectionTimeout** method.
>
>   - The **connectTimeout** method determines how long the client must wait when making a new server connection.
> - The **readTimeout** method replaces the **socketTimeout** method.
>
>   - The **readTimeout** method determines how long the client must wait for a response from the server.

This worked for me with **RestEASY 3.12.1.Final**:

```
    private Client clientBuilder() {
        return new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    }
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```